# Java json string to Serializable

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate, jsonb

I'm meeting this problem.

I'm using PostgreSQL with a column whose type is jsonb in a table. After Hibernate mapping, it come to Serializable. I got one json string from client, and want to store this json string to the jsonb column. Is there a way that I can do?

Comment: @HugoZaragoza However, it doesn't work. No matter I give it string or jsonobject, the error shows: can't insert byte into jsonb

Comment: I tried one method, which seems more convenient. Make PostgreSQL jdbc string type as unspecified, like <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:test?stringtype=unspecified</connection-url>